# Reused Custom CollectionViewCells keep old size properties

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, custom-cell

## The problem

I have `UICollectionView`, which implements method `sizeForItemAt`. I want cells to have the height property which was assigned in `sizeForItemAt` method, but when the cells are reused the size property persists.

So I wonder if there is any way to force reusable cells to change their height?

### Screenshot

Here is the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33Fyf.png

### Code

cellForItemAt:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: answerLetterCell, for: indexPath) as! AnswerLetterCell

    cell.answerLetterButton.setTitleColor(Colors.answerLetterButtonColor, for: .normal)
    cell.letter = letters[indexPath.item]

    return cell
  }
```

sizeForItemAt:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let answerCellHeightMultiplier: CGFloat = answer.count > 18 ? 0.28 : 0.37
    return CGSize(width: (self.frame.width / cellCount) - cellSpacing, height: self.frame.height * answerCellHeightMultiplier)
}
```

Custom UICollectionViewCell:

```
class AnswerLetterCell: UICollectionViewCell {

  var letter: String? {
    didSet {
      guard let letter = letter else { return }

      if letter != " " {
        answerLetterButton.setTitle(letter, for: .normal)
        answerLetterButton.isHidden = false
      } else {
        answerLetterButton.isHidden = true
      }
    }
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
  }

  func setup() {
    addSubview(answerLetterButton)

    let resizedLetterButton = Helpers.resizeImageSize(uiView: self, ratio: 42/48, multiplier: 1)

    /* Letter Button Constraints */
    answerLetterButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    answerLetterButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    answerLetterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: resizedLetterButton.width).isActive = true
    answerLetterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: resizedLetterButton.height).isActive = true
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  /* Views */

  let answerLetterButton: UIButton = {
    let uiButton = UIButton()
    uiButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    uiButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "answer_letter_base.pdf"), for: .normal)
    uiButton.titleLabel?.font = Fonts.letterButtonFont
    uiButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    return uiButton
  }()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` has the function `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` that is called for every visible cell of the collection view.
Your implementation returns a fixed width and a dynamic height with value `self.frame.height * answerCellHeightMultiplier`, where `answerCellHeightMultiplier` is `answer.count > 18 ? 0.28 : 0.37`, depending on a property `answer`.
So if your cells should have a dynamic height depending on property `answer`, `answer` had to be changed during the display of the collection view, which is not possible.
My suggestion is to use in `sizeForItemAt` instead of `answer` an array that has the correct height value for every cell.

Comment: Thanks for reply! There is a problem still, since `numberOfItemsInSection` has a dynamic value, so the cells quantity always changes based on `letters` array count. That's why I can't hardcore the height values. Moreover, I need 2 height options for cells. When the answer count exceeds 18 characters I have to decrease the height of cells and vice versa when the count is less than 18 characters I must increase the height of cells.

Comment: I did not suggest to hardcore the height values. Instead, you have to update your data model when required, and the collection view should use the actual data model just to display it. So you could use e.g. a dynamically updated array that has an element containing the required height for every cell that has to be displayed. You should never use a cell to store data. This is done only by the data model.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized that the actual problem was with constraints, which haven't been updated when the size of a cell was changing in `sizeForItemAt` method.

What helped me is `updateConstraints()` function which I've overridden in my custom view cell:

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    super.updateConstraints()

    let resizedLetterButton = Helpers.resizeImageSize(uiView: self, ratio: 42/48, multiplier: 1)

    answerLetterButton.updateConstraint(attribute: .width, constant: resizedLetterButton.width)
    answerLetterButton.updateConstraint(attribute: .height, constant: resizedLetterButton.height)
  }
```

Then I call it in `cellForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: answerLetterCell, for: indexPath) as! AnswerLetterCell

    cell.updateConstraints()
    ...
}
```

This is solved my problem.